# How to turn a list that was made by using pandas to_dict() with orient="records" back into a csv?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Ok, I realize that the title sounds confusing, and I've been at this problem for 2 days now.

So I created a list, by using pandas .to_dict(orient=records)

```
with open("data/spanish_words.csv") as data_file:
    data = pandas.read_csv(data_file)
    data_list = data.to_dict(orient="records")
```

I then have to make some changes to it, where I remove some of the entries:

```
data_list.remove(current_card)
```

I need to then turn it into a .csv what looks just like it did, before I removed some of the entries.

```
data_list.to_csv(path_or_buf="words_to_learn.csv", mode="w", index_label=False, index=False)
```

But this doesn't work, because it is now a list. Is there a way to turn the data_list back into a format just like it was before I used the .to_dict(orient=records)?

I am trying to make the game create a file of the answers that were answered wrong so that the next time it is launched it can only show the "cards" that were not answered.

Full code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import pandas

BACKGROUND_COLOR = "#B1DDC6"


def next_word():
    global current_card, timer, current_df
    window.after_cancel(timer)
    current_card = random.choice(data_list)
    data_list.remove(current_card)
    image_canvas.itemconfig(display_card, image=card_front)
    image_canvas.itemconfig(language_text, text="Spanish", fill="#000000")
    image_canvas.itemconfig(word_text, text=current_card["Spanish"], fill="#000000")
    to_words_to_learn()
    timer = window.after(3000, func=flip_card)


def flip_card():
    image_canvas.itemconfig(display_card, image=card_back)
    image_canvas.itemconfig(language_text, text="English", fill="#fff")
    image_canvas.itemconfig(word_text, text=current_card["English"], fill="#fff")


def to_words_to_learn():
    try:
        words_to_learn.to_csv(path_or_buf="words_to_learn.csv", mode="w", index_label=False, index=False)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        words_to_learn.to_csv(path_or_buf="words_to_learn.csv", mode="w", index_label=False, index=False)
    # print(output)


window = Tk()
window.title("Flash cards")
window.config(bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR, padx=50, pady=50)

card_front = PhotoImage(file="images/card_front.png")
card_back = PhotoImage(file="images/card_back.png")
image_canvas = Canvas(width=850, height=576, highlightthickness=0, bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR)
display_card = image_canvas.create_image(428, 283, image=card_front)
language_text = image_canvas.create_text(428, 150, text="", font=("Arial", 40, "italic"))
word_text = image_canvas.create_text(428, 263, text="", font=("Arial", 60, "bold"))
image_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

wrong_photo = PhotoImage(file="images/wrong.png")
right_photo = PhotoImage(file="images/right.png")

wrong_button = Button(image=wrong_photo, highlightthickness=0, command=next_word)
wrong_button.grid(row=1, column=0)

right_button = Button(image=right_photo, highlightthickness=0, command=next_word)
right_button.grid(row=1, column=1)

try:
    with open("words_to_learn.csv", mode="r") as data_file:
        data = pandas.read_csv(data_file)
        data_list = data.to_dict(orient="records")
        words_to_learn = data.to_dict(orient="records")
except FileNotFoundError:
    with open("data/spanish_words.csv") as data_file:
        data = pandas.read_csv(data_file)
        data_list = data.to_dict(orient="records")
        words_to_learn = data.to_dict(orient="records")
timer = window.after(3000, func=flip_card)
next_word()


window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the dictionary back to a DataFrame using `from_dict` with `orient=records`. Then call `to_csv`:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_list, orient="records").to_csv("words_to_learn.csv")
```

Comment: Sorry, for the late answer, your method did, not work, but you set me on the right path and thankyou for that. If anyone else runs into this problem, the solutions was using pandas.DataFrame.from_records(words_to_learn).to_csv("words_to_learn.csv", index=False)